# Possible to differentate between nothing passed, or one null passed to F(params String[] values)?

Tags: c#, overloading, parameters, params-keyword

I have a function

```
public List<Item> Filter(params String[] valuesOrdered)
{
    //...
}
```

which acts as a filter on all `Item`s.

```
public class Item
{
    List<String> propertiesOrdered;
    //...
}
```

So that if I call e.g. `Filter("prop1")`, then all `Item`s with `"prop1"` as the first entry their properties will be matched.

If I call `Filter()`, then all `Item`s should be returned.

I also need to be able to match on `null` values. So for instance right now I can call `Filter(null, null)` and all `Item`s with `null, null` as their first properties will be matched.

All of this works except when I call `Filter(null)`. It will be interpreted the same way as `Filter()`, but the intention is that the former should return all `Item`s with `null` as their first property, and the latter should return all `Item`s.

I tried defining an overload to deal with this

```
public List<Item> Filter(String value)
{
    if(value == null)
        return Filter(new String[] {null});
    else
        return Filter(value);
}
```

But the compiler just shows an `Ambiguous Invocation` error when I call `Filter(null)`.

Comment: Note that, even if your overload turned out not to helpful, it should have read `public List<Item> Filter(String value) { return Filter(new[] {value}); }`. That is simpler and always calls to the original overload (in the right way), whereas you called yourself recursively ad infinitum in the case where `value` was non-null. (Note that `Filter(value)` was _not_ ambiguous.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen ah yes. Good thing it didn't build in the first place because of the other call:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the overload, then this:

```
Filter(null);
```

will be called as this:

```
string[] valuesOrdered = null;
Filter(valuesOrdered);
```

and not like this:

```
Filter(new string[] { null });
```

So, you *can* detect this, and if you want it to behave as though you passed an array containing a single `null`, then this will suffice:

```
public List<Item> Filter(params String[] valuesOrdered)
{
    valuesOrdered = valuesOrdered ?? new string[] { null };

    //...
}
```

Note that this:

```
Filter();
```

will in fact be called as this:

```
Filter(new string[0]);
```

so there is a difference between the two that you can detect.

Here's a simple [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    Filter();
    Filter(new[] { "a" });
    Filter("a");
    Filter(null);
}

public static void Filter(params string[] values)
{
    values.Dump();
}
```

output:

[image: LINQPad output]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the syntax

```
Filter((String)null)
```

to call the method in its "expanded" form with a length-one array.

If that syntax is unpleasant to you, you might want to define a constant

```
const String NullStr = null;
```

and use

```
Filter(NullStr)
```

instead.

PS! Personally I prefer `string` over `String` but I stuck to your convention here since it was not relevant to your question.

Comment: True, but the caller wouldn't necessarily know this detail so I don't think it's a 'clean' solution.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Still with `NullStr` defined, it is possible the caller does not know about it and too easy to just pass a `null`. In this case I prefer Lasse's answer.
Regarding the PS: thanks, yes I just prefer to keep keywords and types (including aliases) separated by using consistent syntax.

Comment: @DavidS. Well, the caller _should_ know about that. Just as he should know that `string.Concat(null);` is different from `string.Concat((string)null);`, and `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Uri), null);` is different from `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Uri), (string)null);`, and so on. This is general for the C# language, and if the caller chooses C# for calling, he should be aware. In my opinion it is hacky to let a `null` array represent a length-one array whose sole entry is null, as Karlsen does in his answer. But it is a matter of taste, I guess.